# How to copy a string to the clipboard from a script?

Tags: interoperability, scripting

## How to copy a string to the clipboard from a script?

I want the wolfram script to copy a string to the clipboard.

Unfortunately the following script fails to do this.
The same code works perfectly in the notebook.
But `CopyToClipboard[]` seems not to work in the Ubuntu terminal.

```
#! /home/conor/mathematica/Executables/wolframscript -script;

string = "word";
CopyToClipboard[x = string];
Print[x];
```

I think I am looking for an alternative to `CopyToClipboard[]` that works in scripts.

Comment: I think that the function `CopyToClipboard[]` requires the GUI FrontEnd, but 'wolframscript' communicates directly to the Kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the `CopyToClipboard[]` in a `UsingFrontEnd[]`  allows us to use it in scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

string = "Pshhhkkkkkrrrrkakingkakingkakingtshchchchchchchchchdingdingding";
UsingFrontEnd[CopyToClipboard[string]];
```

If a FrontEnd is already running you may have to quit it, and then rerun this script

Answer (score 6):

`CopyToClipboard[]` requires a FrontEnd to work.

Proof:

```
In: Trace[CopyToClipboard["hi"]]

Out: {CopyToClipboard[hi],MathLink`CallFrontEnd(FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard(System`FEDump`makeCopyBoxes(hi))),{{System`FEDump`makeCopyBoxes(hi),hi},FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard(hi)},MathLink`CallFrontEnd(FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard(hi)),Null}
```

However, you can (sort of roundaboutly) run the shell inside `wls` and copy it using your system's clipboard tool.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

string = "word";
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo '" <> string <> "'|pbcopy"}]
```

This copies `string` to the clipboard.
Additionally, `Paste[]` requires the FrontEnd, but there's a similar workaround.  All together (name from @ConorCosnett):

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

string = "Programming is fun!";

copyToClipboardFromString[string_]:=RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo '" <> string <> "'|pbcopy"}]
getClipboard[]:=RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "pbpaste"}, "StandardOutput"]

copyToClipboardFromString[string]
Print[getClipboard[]]
```

Implemented on macOS.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191560/45153) for implementations in Ubuntu (thanks to @ConorCosnett).

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu implementation of Max Coplan's solution

Install `xclip`

> `$ sudo apt-get install xclip`

## zsh

```
copyToClipboardFromScript[string_] := RunProcess[{"zsh", "-c", "echo " <> string <> "| xclip -selection clipboard"}];
```

## bash

```
copyToClipboardFromScript[string_] := RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo " <> string <> "| xclip -selection clipboard"}];
```

Comment: Trying to copy `"$PATH"`, or `"hey; sudo ls /"` will have undesirable results.  We should have used [literal strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 10 implementation**

To simply steal from the answers of @conorcosnett and @maxcoplan the following seems to work for Windows:

```
string = "word";
Run["echo " <> string <> " | clip"];
```